# Métodos ActionResult Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Se eu criar um método do tipo `ActionResult` com qualquer nome e der um return para uma `View` que eu queira retornar algo, funcionará normalmente ou precisa ter o mesmo nome da `View` ?

```
public ActionResult RetornarIRPJ(string Tipo)
{
       BoletoRepositorio br = new BoletoRepositorio();
       BoletoModel bm = new BoletoModel();

          bm.IRPJ = br.IRPJ(Tipo).ToString();

          return View("Detalhes");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, funcionará, é só você passar corretamenta no nome da view:

```
public ActionResult GoToView()  
{
    return View("frmProdutos");
}
```

Comment: Eu criei um método aqui, e no final to retornando ele pra view mas não cai nem no breakpoint. Estranho.

Comment: @AndreeH faz tempo que não mexo no asp net mvc, mas edita e posta os métodos pro redirecionamento da view que a gente da uma olhada.

Comment: Pronto @Thiago Falcão

Comment: heim @AndreeH, tenta colocar o [HttpPost] em cima do método do ActionResult e tenta debugar

Comment: nesse caso é Get o que pretendo fazer.

Comment: Mas a view Detalhes recebe parâmetro ??? Tipo "Detalhes/1" ?? Se for for assim, faça return View("Detalhes", new { id=seuObjeto.Id });